# how i Split the linear layout into two equal parts when include one imageview and another linear layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I want a horizontal linear layout that including one `imageview` and one vertical linear layout that Equally displayed on the screen.

But image button take more than equal screen. I use of weight and give value one to both.

This is my xml code:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"

    android:gravity="right"
    android:weightSum="2">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="وضعیت"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="نتیجه BMI "
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/john"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And this is my screen:

How can I split the page into two equal parts?

[image: screenshot of app screen]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        // put here all other control's  as per your requirement
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@color/colorPrimary" />



</LinearLayout>
```

**RESULT**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make your width as **`0dp`** for both `linearlayout` and `imageview`

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
```

And to get same height , use height as **`match_parent`** in both.

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

You can use,

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="right">
   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1">
       <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="وضعیت"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="نتیجه BMI "
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/john"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:orientation="vertical"
```

and imageview

```
  <ImageView
     android:layout_width="0dp"
```

Change the widths of `linearlayout` and `imageview` to `0dp` instead of `wrap_content`